# 'lsb_release -a' prints an additional line while using it in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, lsb

I am writing a bash script which has a subtask of printing the Ubuntu name on which the system is running.
I did:

```
ubuntu_ver=$(lsb_release -a | grep Description | cut -d":" -f2)
echo $ubuntu_ver
```

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS got stored in variable *ubuntu_ver* but and additional line got printed on the top. The output was:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
```

How to prevent the 'No LSB modules...' from getting printed? 
In fact this line gets printed whenever I try to store something in a variable from the command 'lsb_release -a'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In fact this line gets printed whenever I try to store something in a
>   variable from the command `lsb_release -a`

This suggests that the *offending* line is actually an error message.  Discard it:

```
ubuntu_ver=$(lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep Description | cut -d":" -f2)
```

Answer (score 3):

`-a` includes `-v` which returns a list of lsb modules, which is why you get the message that none are found.

Also I'd suggest just asking for the description (`-d`) and omitting the header (`-s`):

```
ubuntu_ver=$(lsb_release -ds)
echo $ubuntu_ver
```